# regular/notepad++ expressions

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++, prefixes

Basically, I'm struggling with extracting data and importing into a new field. Can this be done:

```
namewithprefix="PS4 | Call of Duty" namewithoutprefix=""
```

I want it to look like this

```
namewithprefix="PS4 | Call of Duty" namewithoutprefix="Call of Duty"
```

Both on the same line in the xml document

Many thanks

Comment: i dont have a pattern im struggling with the whole thing :(, the above is part of the line, i just want it to copy the namewithprefix and then insert it between " "of the namewithoutprefix, without the the prefix of PS4 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find:

```
namewithprefix="(.+) \| (.+)" namewithoutprefix=""
```

Replace:

```
namewithprefix="$1 | $2" namewithoutprefix="$2"
```

`.+` will find any number of 1 or more characters, and anything in `()` is captured as a variable. The two variables are then used in the replace as `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: Any of changing anything in the namewithoutprefix= if its all in Uppercase to Propercase in the whole xml